# Can two spirits / atma enter the same body

Tags: atma

I have see this answer below but it's not clear if two souls can enter the same body at the same time:

https://www.quora.com/What-will-happen-if-two-souls-enter-one-body

Comment: The answer should be yes if you look for example
Abby and Brittany Hensel.

Comment: @Wikash_ IIUC, OP is not looking for a body and two souls by birth, but possibility of entering two souls in an existing body. Check the quora link for reference that they have attached in question itself.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Yes, sorry I did not read the link carefully.

Comment: Its Jiva that enter and leaves not Atman.